# Vue js with vuex computed properties with v-for and v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to use v-for with v-model. I read the [docs](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html) and there is no example of how to use it with v-for without performing mutation outside the mutation handler.

How can I use v-model inside v-for without mutating the property directly?

```
  <div v-for="product in products">
     <select @change="addItem(product)" v-model="product.quantity">
        <option value="">0</option>
        <option v-for="n in 10">{{n}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>

 // component

  methods : {
    ...mapMutations({
      addToCart: ADD_TO_CART
    })
  },
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting with this, possible to create fiddle of it?

Comment: Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Comment: No, you can only change vex state with mutations only.

Comment: So how can I do this with v-for?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure I completely understood what you're asking but have a look at the below:

**EDIT**

Updated to use Vuex - but not via v-model as that wouldn't be calling a mutation or action which is required

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: [
         {
                name: 'foo',
                quantity: 0,
            }, 
            {
                name: 'bar',
                quantity: 0,
         },
        ],
    },
    getters: {
     cart (state) {
         return state.products.filter((product) => {
             return product.quantity > 0
            })
        },    
    },
    mutations: {
        updateQuantity(state, payload) {
            state.products[payload.index].quantity = payload.val
        },
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
        products() {
            return store.state.products
        },
        cart() {
            return store.getters.cart
        },
    },
    methods: {
        addItem (index, val) {
            store.commit('updateQuantity', { index, val })
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@next"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(product, index) in products">
        <label>{{ product.name }}</label>
        <select @change="addItem(index, $event.target.value)">
            <option value="">0</option>
            <option v-for="n in 10">{{n}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <h1>cart</h1>
    <pre>{{ cart }}</pre>
</div>
```